# Too much calls paint method

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I created a test component

```
unit Control1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls;

type
  TTestComp = class(TControl)
  private
    i: integer;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Width;
    property Height;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Test', [TTestComp]);
end;

{ TTestComp }

constructor TTestComp.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  i := 0;
end;

procedure TTestComp.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  inc(i);
  canvas.BeginScene;
  canvas.Fill.Color := $FF000000;
  canvas.FillRect(localrect, 0, 0, [], 1);
  canvas.Fill.Color := $FFFFFFFF;
  canvas.FillText(localrect, IntToStr(i), false, 1, [], TTextAlign.Center);
  canvas.EndScene;
end;

end.
```

Here is the problem:

1. Component is drawing in top-left corner
2. Too much paint method calls when resizing form.

[image: Just resized form]

Just resized form.

I have a lot of components, built according to this principle. And when I change the size of the form, they begin to lag (Low FPS).

Standard components (TButton and etc.) work fine

Comment: How have determined that Paint is called too many times? How many times should it be called and how many times is or called?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan look at the Paint procedure in my method. It's increases var "I" each time it repainting.

Comment: That addresses how many times it is called. How can you determine how many times is **should** be called, and why is that number too great.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Component is drawing in top-left corner

Your component is drawing exactly where it is placed (`Position` property). If you don't assign any values to `Position.X` and `Position.Y` the default values 0 is used for both.

> 2.Too much paint method calls when resizing form.

When you resize the form all components are re-painted, also f.ex. buttons. In a test with 81 of your controls I did not realize any lagging (but I assume your actual controls do some more painting than this example control).